# Why is my Silex autoloader (composer) not loading a class?

Tags: php, class, silex, autoloader

I'm using composer to load classes. It does work for a provider, but it does not load my classes folder. This is my composer.json :

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3",
        "twig/twig": "^1.33",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "uploadcare/uploadcare-php": "^1.5",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^2.8",
        "symfony/form": "^2.8",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "^2.8",
        "symfony/validator": "^2.8",
        "symfony/config": "^2.8",
        "symfony/translation": "^2.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Models\\": "app/Models/",
            "Providers\\": "app/Providers/"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my folder structure:

> Webshop
> --app
> ----Config
> ----Models
> ---->>Session.php
> ----Providers
> --public
> ----index.php
> --vendor
> --views
> --composer.jason
> --composer.lock

This line is in index.php:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

But I get this error for some reason:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Session' not found in E:\Software\XAMPP\htdocs\Webshop\public\index.php on line 32
```

And in case you might need it, I can give you the session class of course. If anything needs to be added. Please ask and I'll add it within a minute.

Edit

---

This is my Session top:

```
<?php

namespace Models;

class Session 
    {
        public static function exists($name) 
        {
```

Comment: May be you forgot the use Statement: `use Models\Session;`. And check the namespace inside the `Session.php` file. It must be `namespace Models`.

Comment: If both are correct then try to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 1):

Kyoya solved it! I've forgot to put 'use Models\Session;' in the top of index.html